# I need help implementing my Slider object to display a horizontal scroll bar with 3D rendering

Tags: 3d, processing, blender

I currently have a problem implementing my Slider constructor with an update method that displays a scroll bar into my main class. The code should render an image that can be modified by different properties when scrolling the bar horizontally. The problem resides in the main class, (things labeled with //TODO). I need help coming up with a different idea that will help me approach this problem, (specifically the update method call and parameters in the Slider object). I'm assuming my scroll bars are not appearing because of a fault in my math in the parameters (xSlide(10,20,30....)). This is how it should look like when finished:

[image: Final Output]

However, I currently am having trouble implementing the sliders on the right. What I currently have is this:

[image: My Work]

The images do not match because I am using a separate object. Here is my code so far:

Main Class

```
PShape model;
Slider xSlide, ySlide; //TODO possible errors creating object.

void setup() {
  size(800, 500, P3D); //TODO Not sure how to implement a 2D handle into a 3D canvas (P3D)
  model = loadShape("MonkeyMonsterAssg8AhmedAtteya.obj");
  xSlide = new Slider(50, 150, 450, 0, 500); //TODO Fix parameters for handle
  ySlide = new Slider(350, 450, 450, 0, 500); //TODO Fix parameters for handle
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  lights();
  directionalLight(200, 200, 200, 1, 1, 2);
  translate(250, 250, 0);
  scale(30, -30, 30);
  rotateY(radians(225));
  shape(model);

  xSlide.update(); //TODO Calling draw method (update) to create handles according to xSlide (Slider Constructor Object)...So far no handles
  ySlide.update(); /TODO Calling draw method (update) to create handles according to xSlide (Slider Constructor Object)...So far no handles
}
```

And here is my Slider Class:

```
class Slider {
  int left;
  int right;
  int y;
  int currentHandleX;

  float min;
  float max;
  float currentValue; //the current value of the handle. Ranges from min to max.

  Slider(int xLeft, int xRight, int yCenter, float minValue, float maxValue) {
    left = xLeft;
    right = xRight;
    y = yCenter;

    min = minValue;
    max = maxValue;
    currentValue = minValue;
    currentHandleX = left;
  }

  void update() {
    if (mousePressed && mouseX >= left && mouseX <= right && mouseY >= y - 10 && mouseY <= y + 10) {
      currentHandleX = mouseX;
      currentValue = map(currentHandleX, left, right, min, max);
    }
    stroke(255);
    line(left, y, right, y, 100, 100);
    fill(255);
    ellipseMode(CENTER);
    ellipse(currentHandleX, y, 20, 20);
  }
}
```

Ultimately, what my Slider class does is implement a scroll bar (or handle) horizontally, and includes a min/max which is the number on the right of the bar as well as the ellipse which is dragged horizontally.

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: It's hard to help with general "how do I do this" type questions. Stack Overflow is designed for more specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. Where exactly does the code's execution differ from what you expected it to do?

Comment: In the main class I tried xSlide.update(); and expected a handle/slider bar to be created but instead it did not show up when I hit play. Also, when I remove P3D from the size (to get rid of 3D rendering), it will display the handle/slider bar. So my question is what exactly should I add or change to the Slider constructor (Slider class) so that it the image and slider bars will render on the same run. And thank you for any help or input.